# Package dap-mode is dependency but shows no "Required By" and has not Delete button

Tags: list-packages

After an install-orgie for `lsp-mode` experiment I would now like to uninstall packages again. A blocker is `dap-mode`. When looking through `package-list-packages` I find `dap-mode`, click on it and its `*Help*` buffer is opened telling me:

```
Package dap-mode is dependency.
```

But there is neither an entry `Required By` nor a button `Delete` to uninstall the package.

What's wrong there?

(NOTE: I could just mark `dap-mode` for deletion and `x` it.)